# Magento 1.8.1 : IAS infinite scroll not working

Tags: magento-1.8, product-list

I have installed ajax scroll infinite scroll module in my store, it is installed correctly without any error but it is not working.

I found that a new page is requested when i scroll page and response also getting html with success flag but the problem is html is not getting replaced with result.

Following this code I have written to enable infinite scroll.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ias({
container : '.category-products',
    item: '.item',
    pagination: '.toolbar .pager',
next: '.next',
loader: '<img src="../skin/frontend/orra/default/images/ajaxscroll/loader.gif" /> Loading more products, please be patient...',

});

</script>
```

can anybody help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: I don't think infinite scroll requires an extension.. it just need to add small code in 2 or 3 files.. check my [**blog**](http://kamlekar.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/ajax-loading-of-product-collection-in-project-listing-page-magento/).

Comment: @Mr_Green plz past code here link not found

Comment: @matinict please check answer below with the updated link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find my Blog link helpful. Where I explained how to create our own infinite scroll without using any extension.

[**Link**](http://www.uxrim.com/articles/example/magento/2013/11/26/ajax-loading-of-product-collection-in-project-listing-page-magento/)

Some code from the above link:

```
function sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(url) {
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            //Create dummy element
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = response.responseText;
            //refresh the page class element
            $$('.pages')[0].innerHTML = $(div).select('.pages')[0].innerHTML;
            //append the list to the existing product list
            $$('.category-products')[0].innerHTML += $(div).select('.category-products')[0].innerHTML;
            //check if there are more products to be loaded or not
            if (!$(div).select('.next.i-next')[0]) {
                $('load-more-products').style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    });
}

function callbackFunc(e) {
    if ($$('.next.i-next')[0]) {
        var nextPageUrl = $$('.next.i-next')[0].readAttribute('href');
        sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(nextPageUrl);
    } else {
        //hide button
        $$(e.currentTarget).hide();
    }
}

//Assigning click event to the button which triggers the "next" link
$('load-more-products').observe('click', callbackFunc);
```

Based on this, I wrote a [slimscroll scroll plugin](https://github.com/kamlekar/slim-scroll) to design the scrollbar, which could come in handy while doing infinite scroll.

Comment: Hi @Mr_Green, link has been moved to [Ajax loading of product collection in product listing page - Magento](http://www.uxrim.com/articles/example/magento/2013/11/26/ajax-loading-of-product-collection-in-project-listing-page-magento/)

Comment: @AndhiIrawan Thanks. I updated the link :)