# How to implement js function in list.phtml magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

If Load more products.. is clicked, I would like to work on the following code. Could anyone of you help me please? Thanks.

```
function sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(url) {
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            //Create dummy element
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = response.responseText;
            //refresh the page class element
            $$('.pages')[0].innerHTML = $(div).select('.pages')[0].innerHTML;
            //append the list to the existing product list
            $$('.category-products')[0].innerHTML += $(div).select('.category-products')[0].innerHTML;
            //check if there are more products to be loaded or not
            if(!$(div).select('.next.i-next')[0]){
                $('load-more-products').style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }); 
}

function callbackFunc(e) {
    if($$('.next.i-next')[0]){
        var nextPageUrl = $$('.next.i-next')[0].readAttribute('href');
        sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(nextPageUrl);
    }
    else{
        //hide button
        $$(e.currentTarget).hide();
    }
}

//Assigning click event to the button which triggers the "next" link
$('load-more-products').observe('click', callbackFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Po Po Naing, I am suggesting that instead of creating your own function, use a third-party extension for infinite ajax scroll

Like

**Free:**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strategery-infinitescroll.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-infinite-ajax-scrolling.html

https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll

[IAS infinite scroll not working in magento 1.8.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19557/ias-infinite-scroll-not-working-in-magento-1-8-1)

**Paid:**

https://amasty.com/ajax-scroll.html (It's so good it may fill your requirements )

http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/ajax-catalog.html

Comment: Hi Amit Bera, thank you so much for the link. If i use the paid link https://amasty.com/ajax-scroll.html, I do not need to implement my own right? Thanks.

Comment: @PoPoNaing if you install any extension no need for you to implement unless you need any extra features.

Comment: Hi Amit Bera, Thank you so much for your suggestion.